# Is there a way in R to cast various items within a group to many columns?

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
 df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3),
               date=c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01",
                      "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05",
                      "2000-01-06", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03"))
```

I basically have another time variable I want to compare with each "group", and if I have all the dates within a group on one row I should be able to (i.e. if "time" less than want_1 | want_2... etc. So something like this:

```
   group       date     want_1     want_2     want_3     want_4
1      1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
2      1 2000-01-02 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
3      1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
4      1 2000-01-02 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
5      1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
6      1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-02       <NA>       <NA>
7      2 2000-01-03 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
8      2 2000-01-04 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
9      2 2000-01-05 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
10     2 2000-01-03 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
11     2 2000-01-04 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
12     2 2000-01-05 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05       <NA>
13     3 2000-01-06 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
14     3 2000-01-06 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
15     3 2000-01-02 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
16     3 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
17     3 2000-01-02 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
18     3 2000-01-03 2000-01-06 2000-01-02 2000-01-05 2000-01-03
```

Notice that each date within a group populated a new column.

Also open to other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: What does the other time variable/dataset look like? I have an idea but it depends on how you want to compare.

Comment: actually it is just another date variable.. 'time' was probably not the best description, I just didn't want to confuse people with that separate variable and the date variable presented above. The other date (let's call it date_a) is successive days (i.e. one row is 2000-01-01, the next 2000-01-02, etc.). I want to flag rows where any cell from want_1 want_2 etc is less than the cell in date_a

Answer (score 0):

So I created `date_a` as

```
date_a <- c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04")
date_a <- data.frame(want = c("want_1", "want_2", "want_3", "want_4"),date_a = as.Date(date_a))

crossing(df,date_a) %>% 
mutate(flg = as.numeric(date < date_a)) %>% 
select(-date_a) %>% 
distinct() %>% 
spread(want,flg)
```

Now the downside to your data is that you have redundant rows, and the `distinct` fucntion will get rid of duplicate rows in your original data.